# Pandas Dataframe Fastest way to access multindex dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe that contains millions of records with multi index

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data=data, columns=['AminoAcid', 'AASeqID', 'Atom', 'X', 'Y', 'Z'])
return df.drop_duplicates(['AASeqID', 'Atom'], keep='last').set_index(['AASeqID', 'Atom'], drop=True)
```

sample of data looks like this

[image]

in order to access an amino acid for specific AASeqID I used to access it using .at,

```
  display(AtomsDF.at[(1,),'AminoAcid'][0])
```

where 1is the AASeqID with any atom provided, which return MSE.
the problem recently after Pandas update it no longer accept this.

i can use the .loc, but it significantly affect the speed from minutes to hours

```
display(AtomsDF.loc[(1,),'AminoAcid'][0])
```

i cannot use the df.iat() because the index is different than the AASeqID, since AASeqID is matching amino acid index from proteins data bank for specific protein.

what is the fastest way I can use to get the AminoAcid by accessing only the AASeqID, or can i get always the first row at specific  AASeqID

Comment: have you tried `df.iat()` ? https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iat.html#pandas-dataframe-iat

Comment: the problem with df.iat() is that the index is different than the AASeqID, since AASeqID is matching amino acid index from proteins data bank for specific protein